# Adding multiple values to same key in array php

Tags: php

I want to add multiple values into arrays, for same key.
I have this code:

```
    public function getOnlySellers()
{
    $sellers[] = array();
    foreach ($this->getProducts() as $product) {
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];
        $getseller = $this->getSellerbyProduct($product_id);
        $sellers[$getseller] = $product_id;
    }
return $sellers;
}
```

Here I have for example: seller 1 with values: 100 and 101
Seller 2 with values: 107

But on my code, on seller 1 for example, is showing only last value 101, but not both.
What is wrong ?

And the call code:

```
    $call = $this->cart->getOnlySellers();
        
        foreach ($call as $seller => $products)
        {
        
            $show = "$show <br> $seller has value $products";


        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you add your product id into the `$sellers` array, you are overwriting any previous entry. You could append the new product_id instead.

Comment: I know that, but how can I do without overwriting ? I can have multiple values for same key ?

Comment: Store an array under that key and you can have multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an array of product ids to your `$sellers` array, allowing you to assign multiple product_ids to each seller. This `[]` operator will push the `$product_id` onto a new array at `$sellers[$getseller]`.

```php
$sellers[$getseller][] = $product_id;
```

The full code then being:

```php
public function getOnlySellers()
{
    $sellers[] = array();
    foreach ($this->getProducts() as $product) {
        $product_id = $product['product_id'];
        $getseller = $this->getSellerbyProduct($product_id);
        $sellers[$getseller][] = $product_id;
    }
    return $sellers;
}
```

When you output the values, you could use `implode` to glue the product ids together:

```php
$call = $this->cart->getOnlySellers();
foreach ($call as $seller => $products)
{
    $show = "$show <br> $seller has value ".implode(', ', $products);
}
```